# Layering path formulation

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am trying to implement this problem in C# but I do not know what sort of algorithm to use to approach this.

I have a tuple `(layer, index, section)` describing each box in a set (of boxes).

`layer` refers to the height of each box within each `section`.
`index` refers to the count of each box within each `section`.
`section` refers to the collection of the boxes.

The goal is to find a "path" connecting each of the boxes starting from the left, bottom-most `layer` (i.e. `layer = 1` and `index = 1`).

It will move up the section; and when it reaches the top most section (`section = 3`), it will reset back to the bottom-most section (`section = 1`) again. When that happens, it will move to the right (`index = 2`). During all this time, it will only connect the same `layer` (`layer = 1`). Ultimately when all the `layer = 1` is done, it will move on to connect `layer = 2`

So for this example, the output will be:

```
(1,1,1) // Start from the left, bottom-most point
(1,1,2)
(1,1,3) // Top most section now
(1,2,1) // Returns back to the bottom section
(1,2,3) // Not (2,2,2) as it has to connect all blocks with the same layer 
        // first.
(1,3,3) // Since (1,3,1) and (1,3,2) does not exist, and we have not filled up all the layer 1 yet.
(2,3,1) // All the layer 1's are completed, we can now start with layer 2, from bottom-up.
(2,2,2)
(2,4,3)
```

[image]

Comment: Use depth first search algorithm. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/depth_first_traversal.htm